# Linq like expressions library for java with the ability to compile expression trees to executable JVM bytecode

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, linq-expressions

The System.Linq.Expressions namespace contains a lot of Expression classes for all the constructs that are used in .Net languages. You can build expression trees using objects of these classes which then can be compiled on the fly and executed.

Is there something like this in the Java world, where I can build expression trees, compile them on the fly, then execute them?

Just to give you a very simple example, I need a library that would allow me to write something like this:

```
BinaryExpression add = new BinaryExpression(BinaryOperators.Add, new ConstantExpression(10), new ConstantExpression(20));

Executable exec = add.compile();
System.out.println(exec.Execute()); // <= this would print 30
```

Thanks

Just an update. Found this library that does what I had in mind: http://unkrig.de/w/janino.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to reference other variables at runtime?  If not, this seems kinda pointless.

Comment: In System.Linq.Expressions there is a ParameterExpression class which encompasses parameters, so you can build parametrized expression trees which you can pass values to from the calling program. The answer to your question is yes. My example is very simple, I was just trying to make my question clear.